# How can I make my drop down selections change my total by they're values but not be calculated unless selected

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make my drop down selections change my total by they're values but not be calculated unless selected?

Here is what I got. Any help will be much appreciated.

I would like the dropdown for 4PC to do no change
6PC would add 2.00 to the price and 12PC would add 4.00

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, can someone please point it out to me thanks.

Here is my code for the table

```js
function multiply() {
  a = Number(document.getElementById('QTY').value);
  b = Number(document.getElementById('PPRICE').value);
  c = Number(document.getElementById('4PC').value);
  d = Number(document.getElementById('4PCM').value);
  e = Number(document.getElementById('6PC').value);
  f = Number(document.getElementById('6PCM').value);
  g = Number(document.getElementById('12PC').value);
  h = Number(document.getElementById('12PCM').value);
  
  i = a * b + c * d + e * f + g * h;
  j = Number(document.getElementById('SALESTAX').value);
  k = i * j;
  l = Number(document.getElementById('TAXDIV').value);
  m = k / l;
  n = i + m;
  

  document.getElementById('SUBTOTAL').value = i;
  document.getElementById('TAX').value = m;
  document.getElementById('TOTAL').value = n;
}
```

```html
<table>
 
 
 <tr style="background-color:black; color:white" >
  <th>Menu Item</th>
  <th>Quantity</th>
  <th>Price</th>
  <th>Preferance</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Boneless Chicken Wings</td>
  <td><input type="text" value="" name="QTY" id="QTY" onKeyUp="multiply()" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="PPRICE" id="PPRICE" value="5.99" disabled="disabled" readonly/></td>
  </td>
  <td>
   <form action="/action_page.php">
    <select id="BONELESS_COUNT">
    <option value="0.00" name="4PC" id="4PC">4 Piece $5.99</option>
    <option value="2.00" name="6PC" id="6PC">6 Piece $7.99</option>
    <option value="4.00" name="12PC" id="12PC">12 Piece $9.99</option>
    </select>
    <select name="Preparation">
    <option value="Baked">Baked</option>
    <option value="Fried">Fried</option>
    </select>
    <select name="Flavor">
    <option>Original</option>
    <option>Buffalo</option>
    <option>Parmesian</option>
    <option>Lemon Pepper</option>
    <option>BBQ</option>
    </select>
      
   </form>
  </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="4PCM" id="4PCM" value="1" disabled="disabled" style="display:none"readonly/></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="6PCM" id="6PCM" value="1" disabled="disabled" style="display:none"readonly/></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="12PCM" id="12PCM" value="1" disabled="disabled" style="display:none"readonly/></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="TAXDIV" id="TAXDIV" value="100" disabled="disabled" style="display:none"readonly/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td align="right"><strong>Subtotal $</strong></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="SUBTOTAL" id="SUBTOTAL"></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td align="right" style="display:none"><strong>Salestax</strong></td>
  <td><input type="text"name="SALESTAX" id="SALESTAX" value="11" disabled="disabled"  style="display:none" readonly/></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td align="right"><strong>Tax $</strong></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="TAX" id="TAX" /></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 <tr>  
  <td></td>
  <td align="right"><strong>Total $</strong></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="TOTAL" id="TOTAL"></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 
</table>
```

Comment: As far as I can tell there's no event setup when the select boxes change? secondly in your multiply function you're grabbing all the values from the options instead of just the selected option. Even if an option isn't selected it still has a value.

Comment: I'm just struggling to understand what you mean by: down selections change my total by they're values but not be calculated unless selected?

Comment: each box is a drop down selection

Comment: the script i used didnt work so i deleted it, I'm not sure how to get this to work. I'm sure my math for subtotal is not correct as it adds in whats not selected in the drop downs selectors.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear from your question and your code what you are asking for (it is generally advised to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to elicit good answers on stackoverflow).

It appears that you want to know how to make your program respond to changes in a dropdown, so I will try to answer that with a simpler example than your code.

First, changes to `<select>` dropdowns trigger the `onchange` event, so you want to attach an event listener that responds to this.

Second, getting the selected value from a `<select>` dropdown is somewhat more involved than getting the current value from an `<input>` element: You need to access the `.selectedIndex` attribute to get the index number of the currently selected option, then access the correct index from the `.options` attribute of the dropdown.

The code snippet below demonstrates a simpler example of this in action. If you make changes to the 'Quantity' input or make a choice in the dropdown, this triggers the `update()` function, which updates the total.

```js
function update() {
  var total  = document.getElementById('TOTAL'),
      qty    = document.getElementById('QTY'),
      choice = document.getElementById('ITEM');
      
  total.value = (choice.options[choice.selectedIndex].value * qty.value)
    .toFixed(2);
}
```

```css
th{text-align: left;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Choose item</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id="ITEM" onkeyup="update()" onchange="update()">
        <option value="5.99" name="4PC" id="4PC">4 Piece $5.99</option>
        <option value="7.99" name="6PC" id="6PC">6 Piece $7.99</option>
        <option value="9.99" name="12PC" id="12PC">12 Piece $9.99</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="QTY" onkeyup="update()" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text"id="TOTAL">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What I men't was if you choose 4 piece the total should stay the same since it's 5.99 so I made the value of 4PC 0.00, if you choose 6 Piece it should add 2.00 to the total since I made the value of 6PC 2.00and  if you choose 12 Piece it should add 4.00 to the total since I made the value of 12PC 4.00.

Comment: As of now it just adds all the selections to the total.

Comment: I've been trying to get a script and to make the onchange="whatever" to work but cant figure it out.

Comment: I'm trying to use this code but can't seem to get it to work with multiple rows of the same going into one total.